# Does justice happen, or is it only done or made?

Tags: do-vs-make

When a victim of a crime is expecting to see the accused on trial soon, would it be linguistically correct for them to say

> justice is about to happen

or

> justice is about to get (or be) done

or

> justice is about to be made

Are those variations different in terms of correctness and meaning?

Part of the meaning that the person saying that intends to convey is that they do not necessarily hold their breath that the outcome of trial will be *just* for *them*: rather, they mean that the accused is about to be *tried* (as opposed to never be), and still there is no absolute certainty that he will be convicted. If he is not, justice won't be done/made as far as the victim is concerned.

Comment: We usually say that justice is done, not made.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of court proceedings, justice takes on the meaning "administration of the law," which you can think of as a *task* to *complete* or *do*. By the end of the court proceedings, this task is *done*. Therefore, it is correct to say:

> Justice is about to be done.

As a suggestion, a more common form of this phrase is:

> Justice will be done.

As it conveys more certainty about the impending proceedings. This plays into the meaning you described, which is correct, though typically one using this phrase will also have confidence that the outcome of the trial will be in their favor.